# dynamically How to insert the data from multiple table to single table

Tags: t-sql

table 1 :

```
Groupname   View
member      table a
non member  table b
```

table a :

```
id  key
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

TABLE B :

```
ID  KEY
1   M
2   L
3   H
4   G
5   F
```

Final output:

```
GROUPNAME   KEY
member      A
member      B
member      C
non member  M
non member  L
non member  H
non member  G
non member  F
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 'member' as GROUPNAME, KEY as KEY from [table a]
UNION
Select 'non member' as GROUPNAME, KEY as KEY from [table b]
```

Comment: `KEY` is a reserved word in the ANSI SQL standard .
`KEY` is simply another (partial) keyword used e.g. to define a `PRIMARY KEY` or `FOREIGN KEY` constraint
If you want to call your column  `KEY` (which seems quite unusual), then escape it by putting it in square brackets: `[KEY]`.